# Issues trying to build a random project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, zlib, lnk2019

I am trying to build [this project](https://github.com/Tzwcard/sjrm_rom_ext), which is basically an extractor for specific .rom files. As someone with close to zero experience in coding, I am having one issue after another trying to build it.

The project description says it requires zlibstat.lib from zlib in order to build it, so I got the latest zlib, opened it on VS2019, followed [these instructions](https://tannerhelland.com/2013/08/07/compile-zlib-winapi-wapi-stdcall.html), and built everything, included the required zlibstat.lib.

After opening the project's sln and figuring where to put the zlib related files, I tried to build but it gave me this error in fs.obj: "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _uncompress referenced in function "int __cdecl run_extract(char *)" (?run_extract@@YAHPAD@Z)". This is how far google and my two brain cells has led me to.

I am not exactly sure what I should do to solve this but apparently is has something to do with the run_extract function:

fs.h

```html
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "defs.h"

#include <zlib.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "zlibstat.lib")

#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")

int run_extract(char *);
```

and fs.cpp

```html
int run_extract(char *path)
{
    std::fstream test;
    test.open(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!test) return -1;

    size_t file_size;
    test.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    file_size = test.tellg();
    test.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char [file_size];
    test.read((char*)buffer, file_size);
    test.close();

    jrm_rom_header *ptrHeader = (jrm_rom_header*)buffer;

    unsigned long indexLen = ptrHeader->count_index * sizeof(jrm_rom_file_index);
    unsigned char *index = new unsigned char [indexLen];

    uncompress(index, &indexLen, (const Bytef*)(buffer + ptrHeader->pos_index), ptrHeader->size_index); // use zlib

    jrm_rom_file_index *ptrIndex = (jrm_rom_file_index*)index;
    unsigned char key = 0;
    char *path_out = new char[0x100];
    unsigned long ypos = 0, x = 0;

    for (x = 0; x<ptrHeader->count_index; x++)
    {
        key = (ptrIndex->key & 0xff) ^ (ptrIndex->key >> 8 & 0xff) ^ (ptrIndex->key >> 16 & 0xff) ^ (ptrIndex->key >> 24 & 0xff);
        get_file_path(path_out, ptrIndex->file_path);
        // printf("%04d: file_name = %s\n      file_start = 0x%08x, file_size = 0x%08x, key = 0x%02x\n", x, path_out, ptrIndex->pos_start, ptrIndex->size_file, key);
        printf("%s: %d bytes.\n", path_out, ptrIndex->size_file);

        for (ypos = 0; ypos < ptrIndex->pos_delta; ypos++)
            buffer[ypos + ptrIndex->pos_start] ^= key;

        try_create_directory(path_out);
        test.open(path_out, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        test.write((char*)buffer + ptrIndex->pos_start, ptrIndex->pos_delta);
        test.close();


        ptrIndex++;
    }

    delete[]path_out;
    delete[]index;
    delete[]buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

I thought the problems would go away if I used the same Visual Studio version the project was made, so I installed the Visual C++ 2008 and an older version of zlib, only to end up having the exact same error.

Sorry if I am being dumb and having this entire situation poorly written.

Comment: So you building zlib from scratch right? I built them both from scratch and it all worked fine for me. What configuration of zlib are you building? I would suggest "LIB Debug" or "LIB Release"

Comment: I went for Release, as the instructions said. Is there any  other change not mentioned in the instructions that I should be aware of?

Comment: Nothing I can think of. I used VS2015 btw.

Comment: Tried building using a prebuilt zlib but it still gives me same error, perhaps there's something I have to change in the code? I am no programmer, all I just wanted is the end product of this project... *sighs*